# looping through all rows retuned by sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

i am running through a problem, i am running a query and it returns multiple rows as i wanted, perfect. I had to send message to concern mobile no so i wrote procedure for it that's working but problem is that i am not able to send message to different mobile no i.e. no.s returned by different rows. In short i mean that i want to send messages to all numbers that are returned by query.

Query:

```
SELECT CL.[Subject], D.Name as Designation, D.MobileNo, CL.LetterNo, 
'Please Reply To Our Letter No : ' + convert(varchar(50), CL.LetterNo) as SMSMessage
FROM CPOCMS.dbo.ComposedLetter CL 
JOIN CPOCMS.dbo.Designations D ON CL.Designation_ID = D.DesignationID
WHERE CONVERT(date,CL.DeadLineDate) = CONVERT(date,DATEADD(DAY,1,GETDATE()))

Exec dbo.ADD_SMS_InQueue 'Requires number', 'requires message'
```

Comment: Use cursor to loop the add_sms_inqueue by your written query output

Comment: i don't know anything about that

Comment: Please check my answer , I hope that will give you idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Subject VARCHAR(10)--.....Declare used variable here...,
DECLARE vendor_cursor CURSOR FOR
  SELECT CL.[subject],
         D.name                              AS Designation,
         D.mobileno,
         CL.letterno,
         'Please Reply To Our Letter No : '
         + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CL.letterno) AS SMSMessage
  FROM   cpocms.dbo.composedletter CL
         JOIN cpocms.dbo.designations D
           ON CL.designation_id = D.designationid
  WHERE  CONVERT(DATE, CL.deadlinedate) = CONVERT(DATE, Dateadd(day, 1, Getdate(
                                                        )))

OPEN vendor_cursor

FETCH next FROM vendor_cursor INTO @Subject, @Designation, @MobileNumber,
@LetterNo, @SMSMessage

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
      EXEC dbo.Add_sms_inqueue
        @MobileNumber,
        @SMSMessage

      FETCH next FROM product_cursor INTO @Subject, @Designation, @MobileNumber,
      @LetterNo, @SMSMessage
  END

CLOSE product_cursor

DEALLOCATE product_cursor
```

Comment: Happy to help. :) If my response solves your issue, please consider marking it as the answer to your question. Thank you!